# Recompile when local dependency is changed

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I am setting up a project has a structure like this:

- `components` folder contains lots of React components.
- `examples` folder is a folder uses `components` as a **local dependency**

So, right now, the `package.json` of `examples` is like this:

```
{
    ...
    "devDependencies": {
        "components": "../components"
        ...
    }
}
```

And I want the `example` to *recompile* when I change the code in `components`.

Any idea how can I do this?

---

**EDIT**

My project structure is like this, and I am using `webpack`.

```
.
+-- components
|   +-- index.js
|   +-- package.json
+-- examples
    +-- index.js
    +-- package.json
```

Comment: What build tool are you using? webpack ?

Comment: yes. I am using `webpack`

Answer (score 1):

If your project is using webpack then hot relaoding will work :[https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/](http://webpack%20hot%20reloading)
Otherwise if it is just node you can use a server like nodemon eg:

```
$ npm install nodemon -g
$ nodemon app.js
```

This automatically pick up changes.

Comment: in my understandings, the `examples` only gets the code from `components` when `npm install`.

Comment: When any changes are made to the code, nodemon automatically reloads files.

Comment: I know it. But `examples` and `components` are separate folders with separate `package.json` files.
And I am using `webpack` btw.